# cURL <-> Netty: getContent over 1024 characters

Tags: java, http, netty

I am using [LittleProxy](http://www.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/) which implements [Netty](http://netty.io) .
I am trying to receive the content of an HTTP request (which contains XML).

This works perfectly, until I receive content over 1024 characters (bytes?).
I still see the request coming in, and I can see the correct content-length from the HTTP header. However, the content is not returned at all (empty string).

How can I receive more content? My HTTP requests contain SOAP message sent by cURL who will definitely exceed 1024 bytes.

Comment: Add code. Please. We won't be able to solve your problem without knowing it...

Comment: I am using the LittleProxy source code almost unaltered... The code is here: https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy

Comment: Hmmm, I am starting to suspect this a cURL problem (which I am using to send a HTTP POST request with XML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a cURL problem, apparently there are some complications when sending a file over 1024 bytes.

Since I used cURL purely for testing purposes, I moved to a simple Java program to send my SOAP messages. Now, LittleProxy (or Netty) handles the content just fine, way passed 1024 bytes.